# Suppress generation of _id on insert via PHP mongoDB driver on a capped collection

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a capped collection without an _id index and I don't need the _id at all,
but the PHP mongo driver always adds an _id on insert.

[It is possible to suppress the automatic generation of an _id with the mongo shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-autoIndexId)

How can I supress the _id on insert with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get rid of _id , but you can overwrite it.
So you can insert 1 column data into _id field.

eg.

```
$myCollection->insert(array("_id" => 2000, "data" => "someData));
```

Comment: Okay, i will use the _id as timestamp / new MongoDate() thx :)

Comment: But you have to be careful that the _id values are unique, as it is a unique index. See http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/9781449306779/implementation-tips/i_sect12_d1e1208

Comment: Its a capped collection, so the _id doesn't have to be unique - in this case it ist not n index at all

Comment: great then, overwrite your data on.